# Return undefined answer from multer

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express, multer

I am using multer in my nodejs application for uploading files. And angularjs for the front end part. Once I click upload image, on the console I am getting undefined answer. Can any one help me to solve the problem.
Here I am pasting the code.
**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination:function(req,file,cb){
cb(null,'public/upload/');
},
filename:function(req,file,cb){
  cb(null,file.originalname);
}
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index',{ title: 'Upload image' });
});

app.post('/loadImage',upload.any(),function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files);
  console.log("Inside post");
});
http.listen(8080,'0.0.0.0',function(){
   console.log('listening on 8080');
})
```

And here is my **app.js** angularjs code

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate']);
$scope.img={};
app.controller('Ctrl',function ($scope,$http){
        $scope.loadImage = function(){          
  $http.post('/loadImage',$scope.img).success(function(data){
    console.log('Posted successfully');
  }).error(function(data){
    console.error('error');
  })
    };
```

And my HTML code:

```
<form ng-submit="loadImage()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" />
</form>
```

On the console I am getting **Undefined and Inside post**. And on the browser console I am getting **posted successfully** Can any one please help me to solve this. Instead of **undefined** I should get loaded file information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how i used Multer to upload an image

```
var multer = require('multer');

exports.loadImage = function (req, res) {
var upload = multer({
        inMemory: true,
        limits: {fileSize: 1024 * 1024 }
    }).single('newPicture');

upload(req, res, function (uploadError) {
    if (uploadError) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'errorUploadingPicture' });
    }
    else {
        var profileImage = 'No data uploaded';
        // this is where the photo data is
        if (req.file && req.file.buffer) {
            profileImage = req.file.buffer;
        }
        return res.json(profileImage );           
    }
});
```

};

Answer (score 1):

This is all assuming you are sending your file correct

try

```
var uploadType = upload.any()
```

and change

```
app.post('/loadImage',upload.any(),function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files);
  console.log("Inside post");
});
```

to

```
app.post('/loadImage',uploadType,function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files);
  console.log("Inside post");
});
```

if you are attempting to only get one file at a time then instead,

```
var uploadType = upload.single('file')

app.post('/loadImage',uploadType,function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.files);
  console.log("Inside post");
});
```